# Parse response from request and redirect to login window

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, angular10

I'm trying to implement login interceptor for video content with Angular with Spring Boot.

Endpoint for video download:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/play_video/{video_id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public void stream(
            @PathVariable("video_id") String video_id,
            @RequestHeader(value = "Range", required = false) String rangeHeader,
            HttpServletResponse response, @CurrentSecurityContext(expression="authentication") Authentication authentication) {

        try {
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            long rangeStart = 0;
            long rangeEnd;
            String filePathString = "/opt/videos/" + video_id + ".mp4";
            Path filePath = Paths.get(filePathString);
            Long fileSize = Files.size(filePath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePathString, "r");
            try (file) {
                if (rangeHeader == null) {
                    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
                    response.setHeader("Content-Length", fileSize.toString());
                    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
                    long pos = rangeStart;
                    file.seek(pos);
                    while (pos < fileSize) {
                        file.read(buffer);
                        os.write(buffer);
                        pos += buffer.length;
                    }
                    os.flush();
                    return;
                }

                String[] ranges = rangeHeader.split("-");
                rangeStart = Long.parseLong(ranges[0].substring(6));
                if (ranges.length > 1) {
                    rangeEnd = Long.parseLong(ranges[1]);
                } else {
                    rangeEnd = fileSize - 1;
                }
                if (fileSize < rangeEnd) {
                    rangeEnd = fileSize - 1;
                }

                String contentLength = String.valueOf((rangeEnd - rangeStart) + 1);
                response.setHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
                response.setHeader("Content-Length", contentLength);
                response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
                response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes" + " " + rangeStart + "-" + rangeEnd + "/" + fileSize);
                response.setStatus(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT.value());
                long pos = rangeStart;
                file.seek(pos);
                while (pos < rangeEnd) {
                    file.read(buffer);
                    os.write(buffer);
                    pos += buffer.length;
                }
                os.flush();

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        }

    }
```

Spring security configuration:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .....
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/order/create").permitAll()

                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and().csrf().disable();

    }
```

Angular code to get the content:

```
 return next.handle(request).pipe(
          map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
              console.log('event--->>>', event);
            }
            return event;
          }),
          catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(error.error.error);
            if (error.status === 401) {
              this.router.navigate(['login']);
            }
            return throwError(error);
          }));
        }
```

I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8090/engine/product/play_video/1 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
zone-evergreen.js:2845 GET http://localhost:8090/engine/product/play_video/1 404

Show 228 more frames
core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (auth-interceptor.ts:52)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:27)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at CatchSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:30)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1691)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27492)
```

I want when I get permission error to redirect the user to make OAuth2 authentication in order to get JWT token. Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Security docs provide many options, assuming that you're using a custom OAuth2 server you can use a configuration like this:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          okta:
            client-id: okta-client-id
            client-secret: okta-client-secret
        provider:
          okta:
            authorization-uri: https://your-subdomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/authorize
            token-uri: https://your-subdomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/token
            user-info-uri: https://your-subdomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: sub
            jwk-set-uri: https://your-subdomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/keys
```

In the example you provided, it seems you're using Angular to perform the redirect (so you're basically ignoring the 'Location:' header of the response anyway). Since the response status-code in your example is 404, I'm suspecting something else is wrong. You might want to try to use curl or postman to debug the request and analyse the response. I noticed you have configured `formLogin`, which might be incorrect if this SpringBoot app is used as a 'Resource Server'.